# error determining status: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container:

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have kubernets cluster with three nodes. when i scaled down one node the pods are shifted to other node in  the cluster but got above issue
error determining status: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container:

Comment: describe the pod and share the output